# Can't change materials of model from FBX

Tags: unity, fbx, materials

I was used 5.x before, and that version when I loaded FBX, Unity generated each material automatically, so I can change them like assigning textures or change shader.

And now I switched to 2017.3, and when I imported FBX, now Unity didn't generate materials anymore. I can see the properties of each material but every parameter is locked. It seems materials are inside of model and can't change like animation clips.

[image]

Some of model has multiple materials, so I can't generate manually and assign them. I'm creating mobile game so I really need to change the shader to mobile shader, not standard(PBR).

How to change materials of model from FBX in Unity 2017.3? Note that model created from Blender 2.7c and exported as FBX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't change default material directly, however I can make a new material and use instead, I can edit them from inspector. Or I can remap the material or for legacy support, Unity also have functionality to export all internal materials so I can edit them.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the import settings inspector for your model, change from "Use Embedded Materials" to "Use External Materials (Legacy)".

You will then have a Materials Folder to modify.

[image: Screenshot of import settings inspector showing Use External Materials setting]

Answer (score -1):

You can change model prefab material, by selecting material avalible in assets.
As I good understand your problem that should be what you need.

Comment: I have the same issue with imported models.
The suggestion from kacbu doesn't work for me.
I can add new materials and replace them on the model but I can't change an existing material.
How weird is that?